# Which one is correct: just know, just knew, or have just known?

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

For as long as I can remember, I distinguish past tense from perfect tense from the *intention* of the sentence. If the sentence intends to emphasise on the time, then it's past tense. If the sentence intends to emphasise on the "finish-ment" of something, then perfect tense it is. And past perfect is just the finish-ment of something at time point of reference in the past.

And then I use the rule of thumb that everything with "just" usually is having "perfect" tense somewhere in the sentence, whether it's perfect tense, past perfect tense, or future perfect tense.

My wife had just posted a picture in her instagram saying that:

"Having this phone for a year, yet I just knew my phone camera has automatic flash feature."

I corrected her that she should use "yet I have just known" instead of "just knew" because I think it's perfect tense. But she insisted that this is a past tense because the event of "knowing" is happened in the past.

Which one is true? And can you help give some explanation? Thanks.

Comment: I think including the word ***yet*** is at least stylistically clumsy there, if not actually "ungrammatical". You seem to be using it as a sort of "conjunction" between two subordinate/relative clauses with no *main* clause. The natural placement for the perfect would be *Having **had** this phone for a year, I [just? **obviously?**] knew my phone camera has [an] automatic flash feature.* I can't think of a context where *"yet I have just known"* would be idiomatically likely (I can just about contrive unlikely contexts, but it's not immediately "natural").

Comment: Note that you're using ***Having had X...*** as  a "fronted relative clause" (always ended with a comma), which should normally be followed by a main clause in straightforward *Subject+Verb+Object* format. That's so ***Subject*** is properly associated with the earlier ***having*** (otherwise you've left a "dangling participle", which is what your version looks like to me).

Comment: I do suspect the intended meaning is _I just discovered_. You can not convey that meaning with either _I just knew_ or _I have just known_.

Comment: @oerkelens but from your sentence, it makes that "just" is not always have to be interpreted as inducing "perfect tense" ?

Comment: @ChenLiYong I am not aware of any rule like that about the use of _just_. If anyone told you that _just_ should be followed by a perfect tense (present, past or future) they were wrong. Even your wife's _I just knew_ is grammatically fine, it just means something completely different: _All this time, I just knew something was wrong_ means that during all this time you had a distinct feeling that something was wrong.

Comment: @FumbleFingers your explanation kinda confusing me, but do you ultimately saying about "incomplete sentence", like some words that is banned for starting sentences such as "but ?

Comment: I'm hearing all kinds of strange things that are not rules. Why would anyone want to "ban" a word from starting a sentence, and specifically, why would the poor word "but" be banned from it?

Comment: Usually, it's supposed to be a one sentence, like "I love to eat chocolate, but I don't want to become fat." Some people likes to split that sentence into "I love to eat chocolate. But I don't want to become fat." In this case, if the first sentence is omitted, the second sentence will makes less sense in case of structure, because when someone hear "but", it usually be heard after other sentence that describe the cause. But the first sentence is ok if the second sentence is omitted. That's because the first sentence is complete, but the second setence is incomplete. That's what I (over)heard.

Comment: @Chen Li: No. I'm saying ***yet*** doesn't work in your text. I assume what you're trying to say is that ***because*** you've had the phone a long time, you know very well what camera features it has. So you might have said ***Having had the phone for ages,** I knew exactly what it could do*, where the highlighted words are a "subordinate clause" that must be followed by a main clause starting with a ***subject*** (that's ***I*** in my example here).

Comment: ...it simply doesn't make sense to say ***??Having had the phone for ages,** yet I knew [something].* There's no way ***yet*** can sensibly connect the two elements. You might have a bit more chance with ***Despite having had it for ages...,*** but even then I think ***yet*** would only occur in centuries-old text.

Comment: @FumbleFingers okay, this is probably because of the difference of sentence structure between my native language and English language. What I meant is the sentence is little bit more like an irony, because like you think, as I have already had this phone for ages, I _should_ have already known its features, right? Yet here I am (or here she is) suddenly stumbled upon this feature. Thus, the presence of "just knew".

Comment: @Chen Li: I didn't know that was what you meant to say (which in itself is surely evidence that your original text doesn't work). You're trying to cram too many interrelationships between clauses using too few words (in which context using ***yet*** instead of ***but*** doesn't help, because it can carry various other senses that *don't* apply).Plus you need something like ***discovered*** rather than ***knew*** to express the (recent) change of status. *Having [had] this phone for a year, I should know it well. But I only just found out my phone camera has automatic flash feature.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **have had** <sup>present perfect</sup> this phone for a year but **just now discovered** <sup>simple past</sup> that it has automatic flash.

**just now** is understood to mean "a moment ago".

"just knew" is incorrect when the desired meaning is "just now found out".

"Know" does not mean "come to know" or "discover" or "learn" or "find out". It expresses the idea that you fully possess the knowledge.

Comment: Okay, so in the case of I use "discover", why it's "just now discovered" and not "have just discovered" ?

Comment: It can be *have just discovered*.